# PHP Form Upload Error When Input File Field Is Empty

Tags: php

Here is the code for a form that will recreate the issue:

```php
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" ) { 
    print_r($_FILES['fileToUpload']);

    if (!file_exists($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'])) 
        $primaryImage = file_get_contents($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
}
?>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image">
</form>
```

[image]

When clicking "Upload Image" with no file uploaded, PHP 8 will create this error (I've included the `print_r($_FILES['fileToUpload'])` output for reference).

> Array ( [name] => [full_path] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 )

> Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\cole\cms\phpExample.php:6 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\cole\cms\phpExample.php(6): file_get_contents('') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\cole\cms\phpExample.php on line 6

I have tried to wrap the issue in a `try...catch...` block, various checks like the `if` statement in the above to check for the emptiness of the path. Note, if you upload a file in the form and then click submit, no error will occur.

How can I prevent an error from being thrown while checking the presence of the `$_FILE['my_file']` information in PHP 8?

Comment: did you check with `if($_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'] > 0)` ?

Comment: Not sure what you're attempting to do here. The condition is a bit all over the place. First, you should check if you got a file at all (you can check if it's not empty using: `!empty($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'])`). Currently, your condition will evaluate as true if the temporary uploaded file does _not_ exist or is _not_ uploaded and will then try and read, the non existing, not uploaded file?

Comment: @Ron `empty` did not work. `...['size'] > 0` does work!

Comment: there's your check :) Should I add this as the answer?

Comment: @M.Eriksson thanks for the comment. Yours works as well. I like it better because it seems to read better (i.e., is this file empty). I got twisted up and may have misread other answers for similar questions. I'll +1 and accept if you post. Otherwise I'll accept Rons.

Comment: Well, my approach checks both conditions with one `if`, as if there is no `$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']` or if it was empty, the size would always be `0`, if however size is `>0`, that would also mean that `$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']` is not empty

Comment: `[error] => 4` -> https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php: _"UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE - Value: 4; No file was uploaded."_ - _that_ is what you should check for, if you want to verify whether or not a file was actually uploaded. (An upload with size=0 _could_ still be a valid file, just an empty one.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with:

```
if($_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'] > 0){
// code here
}
```

which will ensure that you have submitted a file, and its size is not `0`

Comment: FWIW, I would use `if(!empty($_FILES['fileToupload']['tmp_name'])) {...}` so only one statement. But super thank you!